# Javascript Prototype requires .prototype. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have some code as part of a javascript weekend project that I'm working on. My problem is in the last line. As far as I can tell, I should be able to just call `Floater.create()` and not have to call `Floater.prototype.create()`. Why do I need the extra `.prototype`? Without it, an error is thrown: `Floater() has no method "create"`

```
function Floater(){}

Floater.prototype.create = function(){
    //do stuff
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //do stuff
    runStartup();
});

function runStartup(){
    loginFloater = new Floater;
    Floater.prototype.create();
    // as far as I know, this should run as just Floater.create(),
    // but that throws an error.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part:

```
Floater.prototype.create = function(){
    //do stuff
}
```

does not add a property to the Floater constructor, but to the [[Prototype]] object of instances created with `new Floater()`. So, Floater instances will have that method, but the constructor won't.

You may be looking to change your start-up function to:

```
function runStartup(){
    loginFloater = new Floater();
    loginFloater.create();
}
```

But, given the name of your method, you also may want to remove `create` altogether, and do initialization stuff directly from the constructor:

```
function Floater(){
    // init stuff here
}
```

Comment: Haha! My mistake for caling Floater.create() instead of loginfloater.create(). And I call myself a programmer :P Thank you!